# Test to show one distribution is bigger than another

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mean, nonparametric

Here is a MWE of my problem:

I measure the size, $S$, of 10 red apples and 32 green apples.

$\bar S_\mathrm{red} = 8 \pm 1\,\mathrm{cm}$ and $\bar S_\mathrm{green} = 4 \pm 2\,\mathrm{cm}$.

I want to claim that red apples are bigger than green apples, but just reporting the means doesn't feel right because there is a distribution of sizes for each colour.

Ideally, I want to say something like "Red apples are bigger than green apples with 95% certainty."

I was going to just Monte Carlo it, taking a few thousand samples randomly from each and seeing how frequently red is bigger than green, but I feel there is some test for what I'm after.

Comment: Anyone else feeling Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U for this?

Comment: @Dave - I agree, but if all he has are the summary statistics, he's stuck with a $t$ test.

Comment: If you are really interested in determining if one object is better than another, and you can use large samples or assume normality with small samples, why not simply use $volume$ as your metric for size?  If you found significant difference, you could certainly claim evidence to support one object being "bigger" than the other.  You could perform tests separately for colors or use regression analysis to control for multiple colors or other factors at the same time.  Contrasts would help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resort to the bootstrap version of Student's *t-test*.

It works as follows:

- Compute the sample mean and standard deviation for each group and
  label the results $X_1$ and $s_1$ for group 1, and $X_2$ and $s_2$ for group 2. Set $d_1=\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}$ and $d_2=\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}$, where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the sample sizes.
- Generate a bootstrap sample for the first group, compute the sample mean and standard deviation, and label the results $\bar{X_{1}}^{*}$ and $s_{1}^{*}$. Do the same for the second group. Note $d_{1}^{*}$ and $d_{2}^{*}$ accordingly.
- Compute $$ W^{*} = \frac{(\bar{X_{1}}^{*}-\bar{X_{2}}^{*})-(\bar{X_{1}}-\bar{X_{2}})}{\sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2}}.$$
- Repeat Steps 2 and $B$ times ($B$=1000, for example).
- Put the $W_1^{*},...,W_B^{*}$ in ascending order, yielding $W_{(1)}^{*},...,W_{(B)}^{*}$.
- Set $L=\frac{\alpha}{2}B$ and $U=(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})B$ and round each of them to the nearest integer.
- The bootstrap *t* confidence interval for $\mu_1-\mu_2$ is 
  $$ \Big[ (\bar{X_{1}}-\bar{X_{2}}) + W_{(L)}^{*} \sqrt{d_1+d_2},  (\bar{X_{1}}-\bar{X_{2}})+W_{(U)}^{*} \sqrt{d_1+d_2} \Big] .$$

Assuming that group $1$ corresponds to red apples and group $2$ to green apples, you reject the null hypothesis if and only if $0$ is not located within the calculated confidence interval.

I used the presentation from Chapter $6$ in

> Wilcox, R. (2010). Fundamentals of Modern Statistical Methods: Substantially Improving Power and Accuracy. Springer Science & Business Media.

Comment: Doesn't this use the same null hypothesis as the usual t-test?

Comment: Yes but it does not assume the samples are Gaussian and it works well for small sample sizes (i.e. < 30) unlike the classical t-test.

Comment: The issue seems to be about limiting inference to a difference in means, which is what the t-test (and therefore this method) does.

Comment: @MickyboYakari Regarding your comment about the classical $t$-test, you may want to study the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/is-there-a-minimum-sample-size-required-for-the-t-test-to-be-valid). The $t$-test was specifically developed for *small* samples with the very first application with a sample size of four!

Comment: @COOLSerdash   I had the combination of small sample size and non-Gaussian assumption in mind. I should have made it clearer.

Comment: @MickyboYakari The bootstrap is good advice for cases when you want to relax the assumption of normality. It is a common misunderstanding, however, that the bootstrap is well suited for small samples. Unfortunatley, it is exactly the contrary: The justification of the bootstrap relies on asymptotics. See, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112681/21054).

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks for your comment. I have always borne in mind that the bootstrap relies on asymptotics (Edgeworth expansions) but is it really unreasonable to prioritise it in the absence of parametric assumptions when the sample size is small? I'll follow your link as soon as I can. Thank you again.

Comment: I'll revise my answer to add appropriate caveats once I have brushed up on the bootstrap again.